Symfony 7 Multiple Entities does not work correctly
Symfony 7 Multiple Entities does not work correctly.
I use Symfony 7 in a test setup with 3 databases. However, the migration does not work correctly. All tables are always created in each database. This should not be the case.  I create an entity outside the default connection with "php bin/console make:entity Logs\LogTable". Then php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=logs and php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrations --em=logs. The commands are executed, but not the way I want.
Here is my configuration in the doctrine.yaml
Does anyone have a suggested solution?
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_1)%'
                use_savepoints: true
                profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
            logs:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_2)%'
                profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
            sys:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_3)%'
                use_savepoints: true
                profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_connection: default

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '16'

        #profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
        #use_savepoints: true
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default       
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: false
                connection: default
                report_fields_where_declared: true
                validate_xml_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
            logs:
                auto_mapping: false
                connection: logs
                report_fields_where_declared: true
                validate_xml_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Logs:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Logs'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Logs'
                        alias: Logs
            sys:
                auto_mapping: false
                connection: sys
                report_fields_where_declared: true
                validate_xml_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Logs:
                        is_bundle: false
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Sys'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Sys'
                        alias: Sys
                                    

        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true


Hi how i solved the problem:
config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml
doctrine_migrations:
  migrations_paths:
    'DoctrineMigrations\Main': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/main'
    'DoctrineMigrations\Logs': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/logs'
...

then when you generate migration:
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=logs --namespace="DoctrineMigrations\Logs"

the funny part is that when you run
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=logs 

symfony knows about correct path
